# Unable to find request IP address when port forwarding because all network traffic source ip is my router's ip

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding

I'm currently trying to host a mini flask app on a linux ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS server on an old laptop and I've enable port-forwarding on my router so I can access the flask app from the internet.

Now I would like to log all network traffic coming to my flask app, and specifically tracking each request's remote_addr. However, remote_addr always comes up as my router's public IP address, and from my understanding, this is because the old laptop sits behind my router so all network traffic would technically come from my "router".

Is there any way to circumvent this? I've tried looking at my router's settings but there doesn't seem to be any way to do so...

Answer (score 0):

If the remote_addr is always the router, the portforward you setup does a source-nat. For your purposes you only need a destination-nat, because the router has to take the traffic and route it to the new destination. It does not need to mangle the source if your old-laptop has a default route back through the router.

What consumers usually refer to as a router, usually doesn't actually route much, it's preliminary a NAT Gateway to translate traffic from your internal ipv4 addresses to public ip addresses. IP networks work by routing one hop at a time and packets with a IP address outside of the network range can also be routed. But your router does a full nat

Setting the device to do destination-nat only depends on it's capabilities and the way your internet terminates. Most devices can be set to bridge mode so that the lowerlevel network connection is forwarded to a router you control. But that depends on your personal preferences and network skills.